# TTNavigator not opening URLs when clicking on links in TTStyledTextLabels

Tags: three20, ttnavigator, ttstyledtextlabel

Trying to make a simple link clicking activity work. I think I understand TTNavigator and TTStyledLabel, but can't get it to work.

Code:

```
@interface SomeVc : UIViewController <TTNavigatorDelegate> {
    IBOutlet TTStyledTextLabel *styledTextLabel;
}

@end

@implementation SomeVc

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
    navigator.persistenceMode = TTNavigatorPersistenceModeNone;
    navigator.delegate = self;
    TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
    [map from:@"*" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];

    styledTextLabel.text = [TTStyledText textWithURLs:someText];        

    [navigator openURLAction:[TTURLAction actionWithURLPath:@"http://www.cnn.com/"]];
}


- (BOOL)navigator: (TTNavigator*)navigator shouldOpenURL: (NSURL*)URL {
    NSLog(@"trying to open %@", [URL absoluteString]);
    return NO;
}

@end
```

I.e inside a viewcontroller, get the navigator and set self to be its delegate. When a link is opened, the shouldOpenURL delgate method gets called, where I will handle the URL opening myself. (I plan to let navigator handle more of it, but want to get this simple case working first.)

I have a test call at the end of viewDidLoad: which fires the delegate method fine.

Problem: I see the styledTextLabels rendered fine with URL-s, but when I tap on those, nothing happens. They don't reach the TTNavigator for some reason and I can't understand why. Feels like I'm missing some simple connection/scaffolding somewhere, but can't figure it out.

How to make it so that the links tapped in the styledtextlabel will reach the navigator delegate? Or how else should I implement this simple case with styledtextlabel? (just want to get callbacks for url taps.)

Answer (score 0):

try setting the window property :

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
navigator.window = window;
```

If you don't have one you can add one

```
navigator.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]
```

You might also need:

```
[navigator.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```